# FFMPEG re-write headers for RTMP stream iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, rtmp, libavformat

I'm using `FFMPEG` to stream video over the `RTMP` protocol in iOS. I'm trying to make a network adaptive system which will drop frames and decrease bit rate (of video frames) if the network performance decreases. When I'm connecting to the `RTMP` server, I first write the headers. But when I'm changing the video configuration, forces me to re-write the headers (using av_write_header). What is the best way to re-write the headers?

This is how I'm writing the headers for the first time (this works). Based on this, how can I re-write the headers when needed?

```
AVStream*
video = avformat_new_stream(file, videoCodec->codec),
audio = avformat_new_stream(file, audioCodec->codec);

memcpy(video->codec, videoCodec, sizeof(AVCodecContext));
memcpy(audio->codec, audioCodec, sizeof(AVCodecContext));

video->codec->extradata = av_malloc(video->codec->extradata_size);
audio->codec->extradata = av_malloc(audio->codec->extradata_size);

memcpy(video->codec->extradata, videoCodec->extradata, video->codec->extradata_size);
memcpy(audio->codec->extradata, audioCodec->extradata, audio->codec->extradata_size);

video->codec->codec_tag = FLV_TAG_TYPE_VIDEO;
audio->codec->codec_tag = FLV_TAG_TYPE_AUDIO;
video->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
audio->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
audio->codec->sample_rate = audioRate;

video->codec->time_base.num = 1;
audio->codec->time_base.den = video->codec->time_base.den = FLV_TIMEBASE;

avformat_write_header(file, NULL);
```

Thank you.